Can't get global sieve scripts for moving files working. local sieve is working well
I am desperate now. I can't get my global sieve-scripts for filtering spam working. Interestingly, the local user sieve scripts are working perfectly.
here is my dovecot -n output:
# 2.3.16 (7e2e900c1a): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.16 (09c29328)
# OS: Linux 5.15.0-118-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS 
# Hostname: xxxx.de
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_username_format = %Ln
disable_plaintext_auth = no
first_valid_uid = 33
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Archive {
    auto = create
    special_use = \Archive
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  mailbox virtual/All {
    comment = All my messages
    special_use = \All
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
plugin {
  sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve/dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = ~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_global_dir = /etc/dovecot/sieve-global
  sieve_trace_debug = yes
  sieve_trace_level = matching
}
protocols = " imap lmtp sieve pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
}
service lmtp {
  inet_listener lmtp {
    address = 127.0.0.1
    port = 10025
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/andreclaassen.de/fullchain.pem
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
  postmaster_address = postmaster@andreclaassen.de
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " sieve"
}

my global sieve script lies under /etc/dovecot/sieve-global
/etc/dovecot/sieve-global# ls -l

total 8
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dovecot dovecot 169 May 15 07:10 spam-to-folder.sieve
-rw-rw-rw- 1 dovecot dovecot 286 Aug 19 14:22 spam-to-folder.svbin

My massive logging doesn't give me any hint.
What I don't understand, the same sieve scripts in the user dir, working as intendet.

I have solved the problem.
I substituted the sieve_global_dir = /etc/dovecot/sieve-globa with sieve_before = /etc/dovecot/sieve_before/
The sieve_global_dir is for include files and not for sieve-scripts.
